# how to get elements display properties in javascript in BIRT?

Tags: birt

Hi i have a table and few text elements in my birt  rpt design file.
i am using birt 4.5. 
i need to display those text elements in the report based on the table's display property. 
If the tables display is'none' then my text elements should get displayed in the report. 
how can i achieve this?

i tried with the following

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(927).getStyle().display
```

927 is tables id. getstyle is always returning null. So how to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

hi the following code works fine

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("mytable").setProperty( "display", "none");
```